# Download Video file from a FTP server in Android

Tags: android, video, ftp, download, client

I'm developing an Android app to connect to a FTP server and download video files hosted on the FTP server and save to a folder inside the SD card. For that I'm using "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient" library. I can connect to the server and get the list of file names on the server from my app, but after I download video files, they get copied to the folder I gave and there size is indicated as 10 bytes and they can't be played(Looks like corrupted). Can some one suggest me a way to over come this issue. The code I used is attached here with.

** Connect to the FTP server**

```
public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,String password, int port)
{
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect(host,port);

        // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) 
        {
            // login using username & password
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error: could not connect to host " + host);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Download files**

```
public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);

        status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);

        desFileStream.close();

        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "download failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

retrieveFile did gave me problems too. Try to use retrieveFileStream.